# multiple queries to get posts from same category?

Tags: theme-development, wp-query

I am trying to make a so called featured category on my theme homepage. In that category I would like to display 6 posts from same category. The problem is that, I would like to devide these posts into three different html blocks.
For example:

```
<div>first 2 posts goes here</div>
<div>second 2 posts goes here</div>
<div>last 2 posts goes here</div>
```

The three divs have different html structure (eg. post image size etc). So, does it mean that I have to run 3 separate queries to get the above posts from the same category?
Or would that be too much of load and I should use only one post query?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Just add a counter to the loop.</strike>

Just use `$wp_query->current_post`

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    if($wp_query->current_post <= 1) // 1 because counter starts at 0
        // <div>first 2 posts go here</div>

    if($wp_query->current_post > 1 <= 3)
        // <div>second 2 posts go here</div>

    if($wp_query->current_post > 3 <= 5)
        // <div>last 2 posts go here</div>
endwhile;
```

Comment: You don't need a separate counter, wordpress has one already at $wp_query->current_post

Comment: ah, didn't know that. Thx, I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need multiple queries. You don't even need to put them all in a loop. For your example

```
while(have_posts()) :
    the_post();

    //display post

    if(!have_posts())
        break;

    the_post();

    //display post
endwhile;
```